# Can I do change DataGridViewCell to format english number in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Are available for converting numbers in `dgv.Rows[1].Cells[2]` from Arabic into English without change the row property `RightToLeft.No`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Numbers into English from Arabic ? Have you tried to replace ?

Comment: The numbers within the dgv are Arabic in a RighTtoLeft direction in the whole raw
I need to make one cell only in that raw to be from LeftToRight